# Webdatarocks exportTo pdf missing column headers on second page

Tags: pdf, webdatarocks

There's a way to have column's header on all the printed page of PDF?

I can see the column's header on the first page but they are missing for the other pages.

here is command i'm using:

```
webdatarocks.exportTo(
    "pdf",
{filename: "test_file+.pdf", pageOrientation: "landscape",
header:"<div style='width: 100%; font-size:100%'><span style='float: left;'>ditta</span>\
<span style='float: right;'>Pag. ##PAGE-NUMBER##</span></div>\
<div style='text-align: center; font-size:150%;'>titolo</div>\
<div style='text-align: left; font-size:100%;'>note</div>"}
);
```

Comment: After some test I understand that the column's header are missing only on even pages (2,4,6...)

Comment: Ach... only on page 2, other pages are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue before. Maybe, exporting to HTML would work for your case:

```
webdatarocks.exportTo("html",
{
filename: "test_file+",
header: "<div style='width: 100%; font-size:100%'><span style='float:left;'>ditta</span>\
<span style='float: right;'>Pag. 1</span></div>\
<div style='text-align: center; font-size:150%;'>titolo</div>\
<div style='text-align: left; font-size:100%;'>note</div>"}
);
```

Comment: unfortunately no! I hope that developer of webdatarocks fix the issue